# How to get byte array of captured image in AVFoundation AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I want to store the `base64String` of image on server after capturing image from iPhone mobile device. I am successfully capturing image but not able to convert in byteArray or `base64String`.

Here in this code `DidFinishProcessing` photo is called after capturing image.
Here i am getting `AVCapturePhoto` object from that object which is useful data to get byteArray or `Base64String` of image.

If anyone know please help.

In Advance Thanks.

This is delegate which is getting called after capture Image.

```
    public class AVCamPhotoCaptureDelegate : NSObject, IAVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
{
    public AVCapturePhotoSettings RequestedPhotoSettings { get; set; }
    Action WillCapturePhotoAnimation { get; set; }
    Action<bool> LivePhotoCaptureHandler { get; set; }
    Action<AVCamPhotoCaptureDelegate> CompletionHandler { get; set; }
    NSData PhotoData { get; set; }
    NSUrl LivePhotoCompanionMovieUrl { get; set; }

    public AVCamPhotoCaptureDelegate (AVCapturePhotoSettings requestedPhotoSettings, Action willCapturePhotoAnimation, Action<bool> livePhotoCaptureHandler, Action<AVCamPhotoCaptureDelegate> completionHandler)
    {
        RequestedPhotoSettings = requestedPhotoSettings;
        WillCapturePhotoAnimation = willCapturePhotoAnimation;
        LivePhotoCaptureHandler = livePhotoCaptureHandler;
        CompletionHandler = completionHandler;
    }

    void DidFinish ()
    {
        if (LivePhotoCompanionMovieUrl != null && NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists (LivePhotoCompanionMovieUrl.Path))
        {
            NSError error;
            NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Remove (LivePhotoCompanionMovieUrl.Path, out error);

            if (error != null)
                Console.WriteLine ($"Could not remove file at url: {LivePhotoCompanionMovieUrl.Path}");
        }

        CompletionHandler (this);
    }

    [Export ("captureOutput:willBeginCaptureForResolvedSettings:")]
    public virtual void WillBeginCapture (AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput, AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings resolvedSettings)
    {
        if ((resolvedSettings.LivePhotoMovieDimensions.Width > 0) && (resolvedSettings.LivePhotoMovieDimensions.Height > 0))
        {
            LivePhotoCaptureHandler (true);
        }
    }


    [Export ("captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:")]
    public virtual void DidFinishProcessingPhoto (AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput, AVCapturePhoto photo, NSError error)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ($"Error capturing photo: {error}", error);
            return;
        }
       // photo.GetFileDataRepresentation()
        var abc=  photo.CGImageRepresentation.BitmapInfo;

        PhotoData = photo.FileDataRepresentation ();
    }

    [Export ("captureOutput:didFinishRecordingLivePhotoMovieForEventualFileAtURL:resolvedSettings:")]
    public virtual void DidFinishRecordingLivePhotoMovie (AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput, NSUrl outputFileUrl, AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings resolvedSettings)
    {
        LivePhotoCaptureHandler (false);
    }

    [Export ("captureOutput:didFinishProcessingLivePhotoToMovieFileAtURL:duration:photoDisplayTime:resolvedSettings:error:")]
    public virtual void DidFinishProcessingLivePhotoMovie (AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput, NSUrl outputFileUrl, CMTime duration, CMTime photoDisplayTime, AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings resolvedSettings, NSError error)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ($"Error processing live photo companion movie: {error}", error);
            return;
        }

        LivePhotoCompanionMovieUrl = outputFileUrl;
    }

    [Export ("captureOutput:didFinishCaptureForResolvedSettings:error:")]
    public virtual async void DidFinishCapture (AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput, AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings resolvedSettings, NSError error)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ($"Error capturing photo: {error}", error);
            DidFinish ();
            return;
        }

        if (PhotoData == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("No photo data resource");
            DidFinish ();
            return;
        }
        //var bytearra = PhotoData.;
        //string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearra);
        var status = await Photos.PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorizationAsync ();

        if (status == Photos.PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
        {
            Photos.PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges (() =>
            {
                var options = new Photos.PHAssetResourceCreationOptions ();
                options.UniformTypeIdentifier = RequestedPhotoSettings.ProcessedFileType ();
                var creationRequest = Photos.PHAssetCreationRequest.CreationRequestForAsset ();
                creationRequest.AddResource (Photos.PHAssetResourceType.Photo, PhotoData, options);

                if (LivePhotoCompanionMovieUrl != null)
                {
                    var livePhotoCompanionMovieResourceOptions = new Photos.PHAssetResourceCreationOptions ();
                    livePhotoCompanionMovieResourceOptions.ShouldMoveFile = true;
                    creationRequest.AddResource (Photos.PHAssetResourceType.PairedVideo, LivePhotoCompanionMovieUrl, livePhotoCompanionMovieResourceOptions);
                }
            }, (success, completeError) =>
            {
                if (!success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ($"Error occurred while saving photo to photo library: {error}");
                }

                DidFinish ();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine (@"Not authorized to save photo");
            DidFinish ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"but not able to convert in byteArray or base64String."` What is the error/issue ?

Answer (score 0):

First convert UIImage to NSData

**Swift 2.0 >Encoding**

```
let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

**Swift 2.0 > Decoding**

```
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

**Swift 3.0 >Decoding**

```
let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

**Encoding :**

```
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
print(strBase64)
```

**Decoding :**

```
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)!
print(decodedimage)
yourImageView.image = decodedimage
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
yourImageView.image = decodedimage
```